# Service and Web Reference crashes Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

When I move the mouse over any of these two or right click any of them Visual Studio crashes with the following message in the event log:

> Felet uppstod i programmet med namn:
>   devenv.exe, version 9.0.30729.1,
>   tidsstämpel 0x488f2b50 , felet uppstod
>   i modulen med namn: ntdll.dll, version
>   6.1.7600.16385, tidsstämpel 0x4a5bdb3b Undantagskod: 0xc0000374
>   Felförskjutning: 0x000cdcbb
>   Process-ID: 0xef4 Programmets
>   starttid: 0x01cb07b7f1bd036d Sökväg
>   till program: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Sökväg till modul: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
>   Rapport-ID:
>   46c92fc7-73ab-11df-b110-002481038dc3

Unfortunately it's the same thing in Visual Studio 2010 as it is in Visual Studio 2008. I have tried to repair the installation, reset all settings to default and Uninstall all plugins I have without any noticable results.

Does anyone have any clue to what is going on?

**Salient part in English:**

> Faulting application devenv.exe, version 9.0.30729.1, time stamp
>       0x488f2b50, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp
>       0x4a5bdb3b, exception code 0xc0000374, fault offset 0x000cdcbb, process id
>       0xef4, application start time 0x01cb07b7f1bd036d.

Comment: sorry about not translating it to english. Someone installed Swedish Windows on my machine :(

Comment: That's OK. I have a Swede sitting behind me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have ReSharper installed? The error code 0xC0000374 indicates heap corruption, and some users on the Jetbrains forums have reported this error when ReSharper is installed - uninstalling it may make the problem go away, which would at least then mean you can contact Jetbrains about a resolution.

If the problem isn't ReSharper (seems it isn't from your comment), that doesn't change the interpretation of your error code. Unfortunately, to get the bottom of this is going to involve going over crash dumps, which is no fun. I'd suggest removing all the add-ins you have in Visual Studio, not just ReSharper, and seeing if that resolves the problem - if it does, add them in one at a time until you find a culprit. If this doesn't help, then you may need to contact Microsoft support.

Comment: I have uninstalled Resharper (after having it installed) and repaired the Visual Studio installation to no use. Still have the same problem.

Comment: OK, clearly not that then. However, some of post relevant still, so will edit.

Comment: It seems to have been the Git Source Control Provider (http://gitscc.codeplex.com/) causing the problem