# Visual Studio crashes updating service reference

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, visual-studio-2012, wsdl

Visual Studio crashes updating service reference

I am trying to update a service reference in a WPF application. I am using VS Professional 2012 with Windows 10 Pro. I am running VS as administrator. When I try to update the service reference, VS crashes without an error and restarts. It gets to "generating service reference client code" and shuts down. I tried deleting the service reference and adding it new - same result. Viewing the configuration also causes VS to crash when the window is closed.

I have uninstalled Git and ReSharper based on this article ([Service and Web Reference crashes Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004785/service-and-web-reference-crashes-visual-studio)), but that did not affect the issue.

I have double checked that the .Net Framework is installed based on this article ([Visual Studio crashes when adding service reference with Exception code: 0xc00000fd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260143/visual-studio-crashes-when-adding-service-reference-with-exception-code-0xc0000)).

I checked the event viewer and saw some messages from the crash (below). I reinstalled VS which did not help either.

1.

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.61219.0, time
>   stamp: 0x55cdaf21 Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1063.1,
>   time stamp: 0x5653653c Exception code: 0xc00000fd Fault offset:
>   0x0004e684 Faulting process id: 0x1ad8 Faulting application start
>   time: 0x01d15872619f85fd Faulting application path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Faulting
>   module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   Report Id: 38f0a9b9-f793-4ca7-a17c-45aa530dd6ba Faulting package full
>   name:  Faulting package-relative application ID:

2.

> The description for Event ID 0 from source Application cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Error Handler Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended.
>   (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed,
>   see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended.
>   (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error reading
>   from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean
>   haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult) 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.EndRead()    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, Message& message)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, RequestContext& requestContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, RequestContext& requestContext) \r\n    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, Message& message)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, RequestContext& requestContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, RequestContext& requestContext)
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

3.

> Fault bucket 107828029304, type 1 Event Name: APPCRASH Response: Not
>   available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: devenv.exe P2: 11.0.61219.0 P3: 55cdaf21 P4:
>   clr.dll P5: 4.6.1063.1 P6: 5653653c P7: c00000fd P8: 0004e684 P9: 
>   P10:
>
> Attached files: C:\Users...\AppData\Local\debuggee.mdmp
>   C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\WER4208.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>
> These files may be available here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_devenv.exe_45af31cd21d42a3d1be8be633b512318962e469b_d353f4a4_09f661d4
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   38f0a9b9-f793-4ca7-a17c-45aa530dd6ba Report Status: 0 Hashed bucket:
>   4cda0bc664361674df99e37ac205f062

I looked for the "attached files" but they do not exist at all. They are not hidden either. I was able to find the .wer file but I cannot include it here because of the 30,000 character limitation on StackOverflow.

I started VS in log mode from the command prompt using: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /log c:\programdata\VS2012Log. It crashed but no log was generated.

Lastly, I undid all my changes and pulled the latest from source control. I am the only one who works on this project, so there haven't been any changes since the last time I was able to update service references. With no changes at all, I tried to do the update service reference command and it still crashes. I just got a new computer about a month ago and this is the first time I've tried to update service references on the new computer.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get it working:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio
2. Uninstall IIS through Control Panel - Add/Remove Windows Features
3. Reinstall Visual Studio
4. Reinstall IIS
5. Install Visual Studio Updates

I'm still not sure what the problem was but it is working for now.